# ECOTree.js: I want to get the latest version

Tags: javascript

I found the great JS tree library named "ECOTree.js" but it seems not to be updated for a long time. Does anyone knows where can I download the latest version? I want to use it in Google Chrome. Any help will be appreciated.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16192/Graphic-JavaScript-Tree-with-Layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop idea of using the old - time moved forward and there are new alternatives which will give you more control over your tree graph.

Check out the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)  - and [here is example](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) of what you want I believe.

You can also check [protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/), or try to google for other visualisation libraries - there is more of them in the wild.

Comment: I am sure you are right! but, unfortunately, I need to run the tree on  old browsers like IE8 which do not support enough SVG or CANVAS. Thus, I think I have to use the old tech such as VML. (p.s. I like your icon.. nice!)

Comment: thanks! what about using http://g.raphaeljs.com/ to create such effect? It's cross browser though would require more effort i'm afraid.